# When the index is numeric then does pandas perform implicit or explicit slicing, and whether inclusion of end can be controlled?

Tags: pandas

Implicit slicing is inclusive of end, where as explicit slicing doesn't include end.

When the index is numeric, then does slicing using numeric result in implicit or explicit slicing?

When index is numeric, then can we control whether or not slicing will include the end?

Answer (score 0):

[`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is always inclusive, while [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) excludes the upper bound:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': list('ABCDEFG')})

  col
0   A
1   B
2   C
3   D
4   E
5   F
6   G

df.loc[2:4]

  col
2   C
3   D
4   E

df.iloc[2:4]

  col
2   C
3   D
```